# python - subprocess windows batch commands?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, subprocess

i want to format a drive using `subprocess` and getting the windows command prompt to pop-up to see the results, but when doing this:

```
subprocess.Popen(["FORMAT", drive, "/FS:FAT32", "/A:32K"], shell=True).communicate()
```

i get this error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

any help?

Comment: you need `shell=True` I believe

Comment: oh, my bad, a typo when writing this... edited...

Comment: try using its real name instead maybe (format.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subprocess.Popen(["format.com", drive, "/FS:FAT32", "/A:32K"], shell=True).communicate()
```

you can find out by typeing `where FORMAT` in your cmd shell (not python shell ... obv.)

Comment: (which should be in your %Path%)

Comment: i'm having more problems... if i set `shell=true`, it works but the command prompt window doesn't shows up, and the `FORMAT` command needs some user input after being executed :/

Comment: use `subprocess.Popen(["cmd","/K","FORMAT SOME ARGS"]).communicate()` or something like that...

Comment: if you put the full path to format.com you can set shell=False also